# ¿Cómo Cambiar clase mediante una condición?

Tags: angularjs

Quiero cambiar de clase según una condición

```
ng-if="vm.text == ''" ng-class=" 'disabled' : ''"
```

Pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar una clase en angular, necesitás hacerlo siguiente:

```
ng-class="{'nombre-clase': condicion}"
```

Ejemplo funcional: http://plnkr.co/edit/TsM2T1h0fuf5GXTkHZB9?p=preview

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, en caso contrario, no dudes en preguntar nuevamente.

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo real porfavor!!!

Comment: armo un plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

puedes establecer diferentes clases dependiendo la condición.

asa lo utilizo con el framework ionic usando angular

```
[ngClass]="{'miclase1': condicion1, 'miclase2': condicion2}"
```

talvez  le pueda servir a alguien.

Comment: Podrias aclarar que aporta esto a la respuesta ya aceptada que dice basicamente lo mismo? mira por favor [answer]